# processing pages in asp.net

Tags: .net, asp.net

i'm new to asp.net, but familiar with c#, .net. i want to write a cms for asp.net, which has the pages of the website in a database. these pages contain asp controls, like asp:Repeater which have to be processed after loading the page from the database, and before sending it to the client like a normal aspx page.

i have no idea how to do this, does anybody has some hints where to start (classes that have to be used, or links with some info).

thanks !

Comment: "i want to write a cms for asp.net" -> Hmm. Only for exersice? Otherwise I'd suggest that you take an existing one...

Answer (score 2):

You should check the existing CMS open source projects like DotNetNuke, Umbraco or Kentico

http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/Categories.aspx?category=ContentMgmt